# StringVar doesn't working

Tags: python, tkinter

I've searching for a question related to this code's problem and I can't found anything.
I've thought that maybe somebody could help me if I post my trouble here.

The problem with this class is that the StingVar self.text_incl doesn't shows up in the screen. 
I've introduced a print to test if the object was created correctly and yes, it does work. Nevertheless, when i call the StringVar from within the incl object, it doesn't shows up in the screen

I'll show you a screenshot of the tkinter's window.

[image: Screenshot]

```
class Data_window:

    def __init__(self, index):

        import os
        import sys

        import get_elements
        elements = get_elements.Get_elements(sys.argv[1], index)

        import Tkinter as tk
        self.data_root = tk.Tk()
        self.data_root.geometry("300x200")
        self.data_root.title("Satellite data")

        self.widgets()

        self.data_root.mainloop()

    def widgets(self):

        satellite_data = tk.LabelFrame(self.data_root, text="Satellite")
        satellite_data.grid(column = 0, row = 0, columnspan = 1, rowspan = 1)

        label_name = tk.Label(satellite_data, text="Name")
        label_name.grid(column = 0, row = 0, columnspan = 1, rowspan = 1)

        file_name = tk.Label(satellite_data, text="File")
        file_name.grid(column = 0, row = 1, columnspan = 1, rowspan = 1)

        orbital_data = tk.LabelFrame(self.data_root, text="Orbital elements")
        orbital_data.grid(column = 0, row = 1, columnspan = 1, rowspan = 1)

        label_incl = tk.Label(orbital_data, text="Inclination")
        label_incl.grid(column = 0, row = 0, columnspan = 1, rowspan = 1)

        self.text_incl = tk.StringVar()

        self.text_incl.set("test")

        print self.text_incl.get()

        incl = tk.Label(orbital_data, textvariable = self.text_incl)

        incl.grid(column = 1, row = 0, columnspan = 1, rowspan = 1)
```

Comment: I can't duplicate the problem on OSX. Are you certain this is the exact code?

Comment: The code is a bit longer. [link](https://github.com/sgongar/tests/blob/master/gui.py)

Comment: You have another problem in your code that isn't visible in the question. Your code is calling `tk.Tk()` twice, which is almost certainly going to cause you problems. There is virtually never a case where creating more than one instance is the right thing to do. That could be contributing to the problem.

Comment: Works! I replace `root = tk.Tk()` for `self.data_root = tk.Toplevel()` and works! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The are several things that could be contributing to the problem, and maybe it's not any one thing but a combination of things. I can't duplicate the problem, but my guess is that your combination of options is not allowing the widgets to grow to the right size, so part of the contents of the frames are being chopped off.

For example, you don't add the "sticky" option for the widgets, so they don't grow to fill the space allotted to them inside the frame.  You also don't use the sticky option on the labelframes, so they also won't expand to fill their area in their parent either. Everything is stuck being as small as possible.

Also, you don't give the rows or columns in the main window any weight, so again, they won't grow or shrink. Any extra space is being used outside of your label frames.

As a general rule of thumb, when using grid you almost always want to use the sticky option, and you should always give at least one column and at least one row a non-zero weight.

Comment: Thank you so, so much. I'm going to recheck all the code.

Answer (score 0):

Your Label was displaying behind "Inclination" in my tests. I changed this line

```
incl.grid(column = 0, row = 1, columnspan = 1, rowspan = 1)
```

to make it display directly below "Inclination". So in summary, your label is there, you just couldn't see it.

Edit: here is a screenshot from my computer:

[image]

Comment: Still doesn't work for me. With these changes I get a different "layout widget" but the text don't appear. Here you got a screenshot. [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ehhuc87fhvv92jr/Captura%20de%20pantalla%202014-08-14%2019.40.43.png)

Comment: I see your problem but can't reproduce it myself. This is possibly a platform specific issue.

Comment: Yes, I think so. I'm running Debian 7.4 with GNOME desktop, maybe for somebody this could be useful.